# Hazelcast 3.7 Eviction Algorithm

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Reading the docs on the new [Eviction Algorithm](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#eviction-algorithm), available from Hazelcast 3.7, it is not very clear to me how the parameters mentioned in that section, are linked to the actual **Map** eviction policy parameters.

Namely, the algorithm explanation uses:

```
GlobalCapacity: User defined maximum cache size (cluster-wide).
PartitionCount: Number of partitions in the cluster (defaults to 271).
BalancedPartitionSize: Number of elements in a balanced partition state, BalancedPartitionSize := GlobalCapacity / PartitionCount.
Deviation: An approximated standard deviation (tests proofed it to be pretty near), Deviation := sqrt(BalancedPartitionSize).
```

Whereas the eviction policy configuration mentions (amongst some others):

```
<hazelcast>
  <map name="default">
    ...
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">5000</max-size>
    ...
  </map>
</hazelcast>
```

One assumption to be made is that `GlobalCapacity` is somehow linked to the `max-size` property ??

Any help clarifying this is most welcome!  : )

Answer (score 1):

> GlobalCapacity: User defined maximum cache size (cluster-wide).
> PartitionCount: Number of partitions in the cluster (defaults to 271).
>
> BalancedPartitionSize: Number of elements in a balanced partition
> state, BalancedPartitionSize := GlobalCapacity / PartitionCount.
> Deviation: An approximated standard deviation (tests proofed it to be
> pretty near), Deviation := sqrt(BalancedPartitionSize).

The above are the variables used to explain algorithm in reference manual. They are not the API variables.

But specifically in your question: Yes, global capacity is equivalent and can defined by user with max-size config inside map-config.

Comment: Thanks @javanes! Ok, so that makes sense in the case where I'm e.g. using a `per_node` policy for `max-size`, but how does it apply in the case where I am using a policy of type e.g. `<max-size policy="FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE">10</max-size>` ?
In my use-case, i have a varying number of maps, so I would prefer this total jvm metric over the per-map one, if I am understanding this correctly.